# I'm having trouble auto importing a Class with private members from one project to another on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, auto-import

Anyone on here familiar with VS Code, Mac OS and Dart/Flutter. I'm having issues with Visual Studio Code with both setting up Flutter and get & set methods for private properties. For getters and setters I have to import between files and I keep getting errors. Also I decided to dive into Flutter, but VSC is a pain to set up on Mac which is the OS I'm using

Comment: Could you please share a couple of screenshots that show the issue in your IDE? I see the question is related to VS Code, but the post title is referring to an issue in IntelliJ?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to upload the screenshots. I also use IntelliJ, so that's why my initial question was referring to that IDE. But I'm using VSC for now. Also, I don't think that I can upload the screenshots onto this comment.

Comment: Could you edit your initial post to include the screenshots? It could be beneficial. Also, you can add a [visual-studio-code] tag to reach experts in this IDE. As for the IntelliJ issue, could you please create a new issue and provide more details about the problem you are experiencing - here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA ? Thanks!

Comment: Will do. I will edit my question when I get home. As far as IntelliJ. The main issue that I have with that IDE is auto import for Classes. It's easier for me to import classes between files on VS Code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. What kind of issue with importing classes in IntelliJ do you have?

Comment: So first of all, I'm not able to edit my post. Second, I'm on JSON files now with Dart Futures. I can auto import easily with VS Code but not with IntelliJ. I've read somewhere online that you have to pay a monthly subscription to auto import for IntelliJ, not sure if that's true. But on VSC, I can input 'import' at the top of the editor by typing in '.' and it automatically shows the Class type from the other file. But in IntelliJ I don't get that option. I wish there was a way I can upload pictures to show you what I mean.

Comment: It is easiest to open a new support request: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731, as it is more convenient to continue the troubleshooting. Also, you can upload your screenshots here: https://uploads.jetbrains.com, just provide the uploaded file ID. Thanks!